# v2.0.0-alpha: How to get user's anonymous google ID?

Tags: actions-on-google

In the old library I was using the following to retrieve the user's anonymous google ID:

```
const userId = app.getUser().userId;
```

This isn't working in v2.0.0-alpha anymore, and replacing app with conv doesn't fix it.

Does anyone know the replacement method of retrieving this user ID in v2.0.0-alpha?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get userId like this:

```
let userId = conv.user.id;
```

Sample intent:

```
app.intent(INTENT_DEFAULT_WELCOME, conv => {
   let id = conv.user.id;
   conv.ask(`Welcome ${id}`);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response 